# EXCEL VBA Set timer to protect/lock worksheet with condition(s)

Tags: excel, vba

As mentioned in title, what I did was:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pwd As String
    pwd = "jfm" ' Put your password here
    For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Protect Password:=pwd, UserInterFaceOnly:=True
    Next ws
End Sub
```

But what I want is:

1. Create a timer, let say 5 seconds
2. Check if the worksheet is unprotect, protect the sheet after 5 seconds.
3. If the worksheet is protected then repeat to check if the sheet is unprotect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And see http://www.cpearson.com/excel/OnTime.aspx for your answer on this. Checking every 5 seconds rather than on discrete events (Open, Save, Close etc) seems overkill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
Dim StartTime As Double

StartTime = Timer

Dim i As Integer
Do Until False

    'if 5 seconds have elapsed, exit loop
    If CInt(Timer - StartTime) > 5 Then Exit Do

Loop

MsgBox "Finished after " & CInt(Timer - StartTime) & " seconds"
```